# How would you bash script to combine cp and cd or mv and cd

Tags: bash, unix

I've been shuffling around files and programs and stuff a lot for my research lately, but my bash is so rusty I can't think of how I would do this. For example:

```
jt ~ $ cp foo.txt arbitrary/folder/destination
jt ~ $ cd arbitrary/folder/destination
jt ~/arbitrary/folder/destination $ //Some command here
```

Such that I would be able to be where I had just copied it. Is there some way that I could do this with bash regex's (or maybe simipler) in an alias so i could do

```
jt ~ $ magic foo.txt arbitrary/folder/destination
jt ~/arbitrary/folder/destination $ ls
foo.txt
```

It would totally help me a lot, and I could learn some bash

Comment: FYI, on UNIX it's a "directory", not a "folder". That's why it's `find -type d`, not `find -type f`, and why `ls -l` shows `d`, not `f` for directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a function. You can put something like the below in your `.bashrc`:

```
cpd() {
  cp -- "$1" "$2" || return
  if [[ -d "$2" ]]; then
    cd -- "$2"
  else
    case $2 in
      ?*/*) cd -- "${2%/*}" ;;
      /*) cd / ;;
    esac
  fi
}
```

...invoked as...

```
cpd magic.txt arbitrary/directory/destination
```

or

```
cpd magic.txt arbitrary/directory/destination/filename.txt
```

---

A function is necessary because the alternatives won't work:

- An external script can't change it's caller's state (a script could change its own working directory, but not that of the shell that started it).
- An alias can't run logic or conditionals, and can't refer to its positional arguments.

Comment: the `cpd magic.txt file.txt` (in the current dir) will copy ok, but the `cd` will fail. In the `cpd magic.txt /somefile.txt` will the `cd` fail too. Better to use `cd $(dirname "$2")`.

Comment: @jm666, `cd -- "$(dirname "$2")"`, maybe. You've got a whole nother set of failure cases with unquoted use.

Comment: @jm666 ...that said, this is one place where I'd prefer to pay in brevity than in performance; hence, the (different) solution I actually took.

Comment: Much better, but the `cd` still fails when `cpd file.txt /rootfile.txt`.  +1 anyway :)

Comment: @jm666, I've corrected that behavior, but, yes, this is getting long enough that eating the fork/exec/read/wait penalty is indeed starting to feel a bit appealing. :)

Answer (score 2):

An slower (but shorter) variant of @Charles's script

```
cpd() {
  cp -- "$1" "$2" && [[ -d "$2" ]] && cd -- "$2" || cd -- "$(dirname "$2")"
}
```

Comment: +1. The only unfortunate thing here is the behavior from `a && b || c` -- if `b` is the desired action but fails, you end up with `c` running even if the output of `a` didn't indicate it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, i'm hoping in: if the "$2" is a directory, and the  `cp` doensn't fails, then the `cd $2` should succeeding. (Ofc, here is still a race condition...)  :)